# Springの@AutoWiredと@Validatedを使用した時に発生する循環参照について

Tags: java, spring, annotations, 循環参照

はじめまして

現在、バリデートが必要になってManager.Classに@Validatedを付与した際に
循環参照の例外が発生し困っています。

```
@Validated
public interface ManagerA {

    public void methodA(@valid @argVal String arg);

}

public interface ManagerB {

    public void methodB(String arg);

}

public class mainManagerA implements ManagerA {

    @Autowired
    private ManagerB managerB;

}

public class mainManagerB implements ManagerB{

    @Autowired
    private ManagerA managerA;

}
```

この様な実装で循環参照の例外が発生しない方法について
ご存知の方にご教授をお願い致します。

Comment: mainManagerA(Aを実装＋Validation)はBを扱いたい、しかしmainManagerB(Bを実装)もAを扱いたい、となっていますので、Validatedなくても、くるくるまわってますね。

mainManagerAは、＠AutowiredでmanagerBの実装クラスを呼ぶ→つまりmainManagerB、しかしmainManagerBはmanagerAの実装、つまりmaninManagerAを呼ぶ状態です。片方の@Autiwiredとmanagerは不要ではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます、ご指摘の通り
バリデート前から循環状態ではあったみたいです。
根本的な設計問題なのでご指摘の通り、片方のmanagerの参照を外す方向性で進めようと思います。
未だにアノテーションを付けたら例外が起きたかは謎ですが
@Validatedで関連した要素の走査でもしてるのかなとは予想しています。
ありがとうございました。